# simplest way to prevent accesing array beyond range in C

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if there is any easier way to prevent accessing array beyond range than using `if()` statement.
I have switch case code for arduino like this with many cases:

```c
switch(a){
    case 3:     
    case 27:  
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        leds[ledMapArray[x][i]] = CRGB(0,255,0);
        leds[ledMapArray[i][y]] = CRGB(0,255,0);
        if ((x + i < 8) && (y + i < 8))     leds[ledMapArray[x + i][y + i]] = CRGB(0,255,0);
        if ((x - i >= 0) && (y - i >= 0))   leds[ledMapArray[x - i][y - i]] = CRGB(0,255,0);
        if ((x + i < 8) && (y - i >= 0))    leds[ledMapArray[x + i][y - i]] = CRGB(0,255,0);
        if ((x - i >= 0) && (y + i < 8))    leds[ledMapArray[x - i][y + i]] = CRGB(0,255,0);    
        }
      break;
    case 4:   
    case 28:  
      if (x + 1 < 8)                      leds[ledMapArray[x + 1][y]] = CRGB(0,255,0);
      if (x - 1 >= 0)                     leds[ledMapArray[x - 1][y]] = CRGB(0,255,0);
      if (y - 1 >= 0)                     leds[ledMapArray[x][y - 1]] = CRGB(0,255,0);
      if (y + 1 < 8)                      leds[ledMapArray[x][y + 1]] = CRGB(0,255,0);
      if ((x + 1  < 8) && (y + 1 < 8))    leds[ledMapArray[x + 1][y + 1]] = CRGB(0,255,0);
      if ((x - 1  >= 0) && (y - 1 >= 0))  leds[ledMapArray[x - 1][y - 1]] = CRGB(0,255,0);
      if ((x + 1  < 8) && (y - 1 >= 0))   leds[ledMapArray[x + 1][y - 1]] = CRGB(0,255,0);
      if ((x - 1  >= 0) && (y + 1 < 8))   leds[ledMapArray[x - 1][y + 1]] = CRGB(0,255,0);    
      break;
...
```

`ledMapArray` is 8x8 array where `x` and `y` value may be <7,0>. Here are some definitions:

```c
// CRGB is structure from FastLed library
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS]; // from FastLed library to control LED strip
// Array to show how LED strip looks like, values in array represents leds
const short ledMapArray[8][8] = {{0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7},
                                 {15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9,  8},
                                 {16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23},
                                 {31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24},
                                 {32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39},
                                 {47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40},
                                 {48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55},   
                                 {63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56}};
```

The point of this switch case is to light up specific LEDs from LED strip. I want to show allowed moves for chess pieces on smart chessboard.
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: How does the code in the question prevent out of range accesses?

Comment: Did you mean to test `(x + 1 < 8)` or `(x + i < 8)` in the first loop?

Comment: I meant `(x + i < 8)`.  My bad. @jarmod

Comment: You may be able to write a macro that uses `sizeof` to determine the array size and compares the index to it. This will only work for arrays, not pointers.

Comment: the assignment will not take place if `x + i` is lesser than 8 and so on. But I guess there is simpler way to do this, without that many `if` statements. @IanAbbott

Comment: Thanks for idea, will check it :). @Barmar

Comment: @Frogg1ven But for example, `if ((x - i >= 0) && (y - i >= 0))` does not limit to the upper bounds.

Comment: I suggest to show the definitions of `leds`, `ledMapArray` and `CRGB`. This would allow to improve the answer.

Comment: @IanAbbott `x` and `y` values can only be in range <0,7>, so I think it can't be beyond upper array limit in case like this: `if ((x - 1  >= 0) && (y - 1 >= 0))  leds[ledMapArray[x - 1][y - 1]] = CRGB(0,255,0);`

Comment: @Frogg1ven Sorry, I missed that bit. But then why do you need `case 27:` if `x` is in the range [0, 7]?

Comment: @Bodo `CRGB` is struct form FastLed library, and it's kinda long, so I can't paste it, but it's representation of an RGB pixel (Red, Green, Blue).  I have edited post.

Comment: Is `CRGB` a `typedef` or a macro or a function? The different uses as `leds[something] = CRGB(0,255,0)` and `CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];` look contradicting.

Comment: @Bodo its big structure that represents single led. `CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];` is 64 elements array where each element is single LED, and for example `leds[10] = CRGB(0,255,0)` sets LED number 11 on LED strip green color. I don't know how to explain this better.

Comment: The explanation for the confusion is that the code is C++ not C, and the structure `CRGB` has a constructor `CRGB( uint8_t ir, uint8_t ig, uint8_t ib)`.

Comment: I don't know how it works on microcontroller (ESP32), didn't ever checked that, but I have been always using C. @Bodo

Comment: @Frogg1ven Most of C is a subset of C++. If your project is using the Arduino IDE, it will be using C++ behind the scenes, even if your code is not defining its own C++ classes and templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Answer was written when the question used the tag `c`, not `c++` and edited later. The FastLED library is clearly implemented in C++.

You could wrap the array access in a function that implements the checks.

The following function assumes that the array `leds` and `ledMapArray` are file scope variables. Otherwise the function would need more arguments. In C++, the function will also work if the function and the variables are members of the same class.

Instead of a hard-coded number `8`, the check should better be implemented based on the number of elements in the array. (Something like `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`. I would need to see the definition of `leds` and `ledMapArray`.)

Note that the function implements a bounds check for `ledMapArray` only, not for `leds`.

```c
void setLed(int x, int y, some_type crgb)
{
    if((x >= 0) && (x < 8) && (y >= 0) && (y < 8))
    {
        leds[ledMapArray[x][y]] = crgb;
    }
}
```

The function could also be replaced with a macro which would work for local array variables as well as for global variables.

```c
#define setLed(x, y, crgb) do { \
    if((x >= 0) && (x < 8) && (y >= 0) && (y < 8)) { \
        leds[ledMapArray[x][y]] = crgb; \
    } \
} while(0)
```

```c
switch(x){
    case 3:     
    case 27:  
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        setLed(x, i, CRGB(0,255,0));
        setLed(i, y, CRGB(0,255,0));
        setLed(x + i, y + i, CRGB(0,255,0));
        setLed(x - i, y - i, CRGB(0,255,0));
        setLed(x + i, y - i, CRGB(0,255,0));
        setLed(x - i, y + i, CRGB(0,255,0));    
        }
      break;
    case 4:   
    case 28:  
      setLed(x + 1, y, CRGB(0,255,0));

/* etc ... */
```

Instead of repeatedly using anonymous objects with the same constructor `CRGB(0,255,0)`, you could use a named object.

```cpp
CRGB greenColor(0,255,0);

        setLed(x, i, greenColor);
        setLed(i, y, greenColor);
        /* etc ... */
```

Or use pre-defined color objects from the library.

```cpp
        setLed(x, i, CRGB::Green);
        setLed(i, y, CRGB::Green);
        /* etc ... */
```

Comment: It looks much better than my code. I will check it for sure.